# allowToChangeInstallationDirectory: ture , How to install to disk root

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

When I use `allowToChangeInstallationDirectory: ture` and choice path `d:\`, it can be install.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6sMy.jpg)
How can I install to disk root?

electron-builder: 23.0.2.
Node Version: 14.17.5.
electron: 18.0.0.

Comment: The `nis` tag is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In real NSIS you just add `AllowRootDirInstall true`.

With Electron, who knows. I think you have to set `include` to a [custom](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis.html#custom-nsis-script) file that contains:

```
!macro customHeader
AllowRootDirInstall true
!macroend
```